# Why ALS can be easily computed in parallel?

Tags: machine-learning, matrix-factorization, recommendation-engine

I understand that ALS can be computed partially in parallel because we can work with rows / columns independently to compute item / user latent features but then if we've computed user_latent features we will need item_latent features for the next step to compute user_latent features and so on.

So, my questions is can it be optimized any further? Or the fact we can work with one big matrix in parallel is enough for real applications.

Comment: The alternating inner-calculations will dominate the outer overhead (heavily). In this case i don't see a need to go further.

Comment: I see, it makes sense, thank you!